# Opening Word Document using VBA in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I'm using Access 2013 and created a help button on a form that I would like to open up a Word doc with instructions. Here's the code I tried:

```
Private Sub cmdHelp_Click()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim filepath As String

    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True

    filepath = "C:\...\Handout.docx"
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(filepath)
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I try to compile I get an error on the first line that says "User-defined type not defined"

Comment: did you set references to `Word Library` in VBA/IDE editor?

Comment: I didn't. I'm new to VBA, how would I do that?

Comment: go to VBA Editor >> Menu >> Tools >> References >> and find on the list `Microsoft Word XX.X Object library` with the highest possible number after in XX.X (possibly 16.0) >> check it >> press OK. Then run the macro again...

Comment: The only answer I can accept is the one below by @fabio. Since you commented I can't accept those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check if you set appropriate reference to Word Library in VBA Environment.

To do so follow the path:

```
Go to VBA Editor >> Menu >> Tools >> References >> 
    Find on the list Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library where 
    XX.X is the highest available number >> 
Check it >> press OK.
```

Comment: It is nearly always better to develop with early binding and release with late binding.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't be easier just to do:

```
Shell "winword ""c:\...\Handout.docx"""
```

... instead of creating an object just to open the application?