# Open Word document

Tags: ms-access, vba

I found on this forum the solution to open a Word document from Access:

([Opening Word Document using VBA in Access 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973041/opening-word-document-using-vba-in-access-2013)).

```
button click: Shell "winword ""c:\...\Handout.docx"""
```

It opens that document. Is there a way to 'popup' it above my Access form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must learn to use the *documentation* and/or *IntelliSense* for such simple tasks:

[image: IntelliSense]

Anyway:

```
Shell "winword ""c:...\Handout.docx""", vbNormalFocus
```